# Compare a pointer to an integer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to search though a linked list for an asterisk, however each time I try to use a while loop to compare the head pointer to an asterisk, the program will not compile saying that it cannot compare a pointer to an integer

It is  in print list function:  `while( pt != '*')`

```
/*
 *Description: Construction of a social network
 */

#include < stdio.h>
#include < strings.h>
#include < stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 30
#define PEOPLE_SIZE 20
#define PRINT_NETWORK 1
struct people   
{
        char name[SIZE];
        int age;
        char gender[SIZE];
        int idnumber;
        struct friendlist *friends;
};

typedef struct friendlist
{
        int friendsname[PEOPLE_SIZE];
        struct friendlist *next;
        struct people *person;
}node_t;

void scan_friends(FILE *input2, node_t *pt)
{
        char *friend_name;
        fscanf(input2,"%s", &pt->friendsname);
}

void  print_friends(node_t pt)
{
       printf("%s ", pt.friendsname);
}

void print_list(node_t *pt)
{
        int friendsname[PEOPLE_SIZE];
        struct friendlist *next;
        struct people *person;

}node_t;

void  print_friends(node_t pt) 
{
        printf("%s ", pt.friendsname);
}

void print_list (node_t *pt)
{ 
        if (pt==NULL)
                printf("The list is empty\n");
        else
        {                 // traversing the list
                while (pt!=NULL)
                {
                        while (pt != '*')
                       {
                                    print_friends(*pt);
                                    pt=pt->next;
                       }
                }
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    int choice=0;
    FILE *input; //pointer to people.dat

    FILE *input_friends;
    int i=0;
    struct people people[SIZE];
    struct friendlist friendlist[PEOPLE_SIZE];
    node_t *headp, *temp, *current=NULL;
    char user_name[SIZE];
    int user;

            input_friends=fopen("friends.dat", "r"); //opens friends file

            while(!feof(input_friends))
            {
                    // create a new list element
                    temp = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));  // memory
                    scan_friends(input_friends, temp);    // initialization of element 
                    temp->next=NULL;     // setting pointer to null.

                    if (current==NULL)
                    {
                            headp=temp;  // setting the head of the list
                    }
                    else
                    {
                                current->next=temp;   // else connecting to previous
                        }
                        current=temp;   // updating the current element

                        i++;   // count number of elements added
                }
                fclose(input_friends);
                print_list(headp);                                    
        }

        printf("\n");
        return(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `search though a linked list for an asterisk`?

Comment: That's because it doesn't make any sense to compare the pointer to an asterisk.  `pt` is a pointer to a `node_t` (a struct), while an asterisk is a character.  Apples to Oranges

Comment: @ChrisDodd (and asaelr, on my deleted post) are correct.

Comment: What do you search for? You want to know whether the name is an asterisk? Or what? This is AMBIGUOUS.

Comment: Does this even compile?  There are a ton of errors in your code as it currently is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think you meant to post, it still doesn't compile though, since you can't compare a pointer to a char

```
/*
 *Description: Construction of a social network
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 30
#define PEOPLE_SIZE 20
#define PRINT_NETWORK 1

struct people   
{
    char name[SIZE];
    int age;
    char gender[SIZE];
    int idnumber;
    struct friendlist *friends;
};

typedef struct friendlist
{
    int friendsname[PEOPLE_SIZE];
    struct friendlist *next;
    struct people *person;
} node_t;

void scan_friends(FILE *input2, node_t *pt)
{
    char *friend_name;
    fscanf(input2,"%s", &pt->friendsname);
}

void  print_friends(node_t pt)
{
    printf("%s ", pt.friendsname);
}

void print_list (node_t *pt)
{ 
    if (pt==NULL)
        printf("The list is empty\n");
    else
    {                 // traversing the list
        while (pt!=NULL)
        {
            while (pt != '*')
            {
                print_friends(*pt);
                pt=pt->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int choice=0;
    FILE *input; //pointer to people.dat

    FILE *input_friends;
    int i=0;
    struct people people[SIZE];
    struct friendlist friendlist[PEOPLE_SIZE];
    node_t *headp, *temp, *current=NULL;
    char user_name[SIZE];
    int user;

    input_friends=fopen("friends.dat", "r"); //opens friends file

    while(!feof(input_friends))
    {
        // create a new list element
        temp = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));  // memory
        scan_friends(input_friends, temp);    // initialization of element 
        temp->next=NULL;     // setting pointer to null.

        if (current==NULL)
        {
            headp=temp;  // setting the head of the list
        }
        else
        {
            current->next=temp;   // else connecting to previous
        }
        current=temp;   // updating the current element

        i++;   // count number of elements added
    }
    fclose(input_friends);
    print_list(headp);                                    

    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

My edits have brought it down to only one compile error that you need to sort out yourself.  Its on the line 47:

```
while (pt != '*')
```

This is certainly not what you want to do.

What do you want to compare to the asterisk?  The name?

Consider something *like*

```
while (pt->person->name != '*')
```

Note that this still won't work because you'll be comparing a char array with a single char.  But this should move you in the direction you want to go, depending on what you want to compare the asterisk to.  Note that this is how you access members of a structure which you have a pointer to.

Anything else is just the basics of structs and how to access their members.